# Symfony3 bundle conflicts with FOSUserBundle

Tags: php, symfony

I have struggling with composer conflict.

My message is like this below, I guess `^1.3` means "use more than version 1.3"?.

Am I correct?

I am using `"friendsofsymfony/user-bundle" : "2.0.1"`

It satisfies the needs.

I can choose 1.3,X as message says, but there are still some conflicts happens,

So I am stack in cat-and-mouse game.

What is the best way to solve this??

Or if someone has setting Symfony3.3 with SonataUserbundle, FOSUserBundle, HWIOAuthBundle, Please could you let me know the combination of bundles?

I just want to make user management with OAuth.

Problem 1

```
    - Installation request for sonata-project/user-bundle 3.2.4 -> satisfiable by sonata-project/user-bundle[3.2.4].
    - sonata-project/user-bundle 3.2.4 requires friendsofsymfony/user-bundle ^1.3 -> satisfiable by friendsofsymfony/user-bundle[1.3.x-dev, v1.3.0, v1.3.1, v1.3.2, v1.3.3, v1.3.4, v1.3.5, v1.3.6, v1.3.7] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
```

in  composer.json

```json
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^1.6",
    "doctrine/orm": "^2.5",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "^2.0",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "^5.0.19",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^3.0.2",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.1.0",
    "symfony/polyfill-apcu": "^1.0",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^2.3.10",
    "symfony/symfony": "3.3.*",
    "twig/twig": "^1.0||^2.0",

    "sonata-project/admin-bundle" : "3.19.0",
    "sonata-project/cache-bundle" : "dev-master",
    "sonata-project/block-bundle" : "3.3.2",
    "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle" : "3.1.1",
    "sonata-project/core-bundle" : "3.4.0",
    "sonata-project/doctrine-extensions" : "1.0.2",
    "sonata-project/user-bundle" : "3.2.4",
    "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle" : "2.0.1",
    "sonata-project/intl-bundle" : "dev-master",
    "twig/extensions" : "1.0.*",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle" : "dev-master",
    "jms/security-extra-bundle" : "dev-master",
    "jms/di-extra-bundle" : "1.8.1",

    "hwi/oauth-bundle" : "dev-master",
    "knplabs/knp-menu-bundle" : "2.1.2",
    "friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle" : "~1.1",
    "adesigns/calendar-bundle" : "dev-master",
    "symfony/expression-language" : "2.7.*@dev",
    "stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle" : "dev-master",
    "gedmo/doctrine-extensions" : "2.3.12",
    "php-http/guzzle6-adapter" : "1.1.1",
    "league/uri" : "4.2.2",

    "jms/serializer-bundle" : "dev-master",
    "sonata-project/classification-bundle" : "dev-master",
    "sonata-project/datagrid-bundle" : "2.2.1"
```

Comment: `^1.3` in composer means `>= 1.3.0 < 2.0.0` https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/versions.md

Comment: You will need to require `SonataUserBundle` `dev-*` due to the version constraints on Symfony in `SonataUserBundle` `3.*` being bound to symfony `^2.3`. 
However SonataUserBundle dev will require you to use `PHP 7.0` or higher.

Comment: additionally you can use `php composer.phar why-not "sonata-project/user-bundle" dev-*` to determine why composer fails to upgrade a to the desired version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the latest version of `friendsofsymfony/user-bundle` is not yet supported with/by `sonata-project/user-bundle`

You're using:

```
"friendsofsymfony/user-bundle" : "2.0.1",
```

You need to be using:

```
"friendsofsymfony/user-bundle" : "^1.3",
```

Comment: Except the FOSUserBundle 1.3 will not work with S3.x.  Really kind of a mess.

Comment: `sonata-project/user-bundle` 3.x is not compatible with Symfony  3 either. https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataUserBundle/blob/3.x/composer.json

Comment: Thanks I found out the conclusion, I should not use symfony3.0 yet.I will try again after sonata user bundle becomes compatible.